# How to stop verbatim from converting tabs to spaces?

Tags: verbatim, sourcecode

I am using `verbatim` to put some sample code in my document:

```
\begin{verbatim}  
[start]        printf{"Start command received"};
[stop]         printf{"Stop command received"};
\end{verbatim}
```

I would like latex to preserve the tabs but instead what I am getting as output is this:

```
[start] printf{"Start command received"};
[stop] printf{"Stop command received"};
```

As you can see the tab is converted to a space. Is it not defeating the entire purpose of writing something inside `verbatim`? Is this **normal behaviour** for the `verbatim` environment?

P.S. I am using TexLive 2014 and TexStudio 2.8.8

Comment: Depends on your point of view: the usual TeX position is that tabs are not a good plan as they are visually the same as spaces. I note that StackExchange agree: your 'literal' text here contains spaces :-)

Comment: so this means if I have a long code section I have to convert all the tabs to spaces?

Comment: No: there are fixes, don't worry (hence that being a comment not an answer!)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

Some text to surround the verbatim
\begin{Verbatim}[obeytabs]
[start]         printf{"Start command received"};
[stop]          printf{"Stop command received"};
\end{Verbatim}
Some text to surround the verbatim
\begin{Verbatim}[obeytabs,tabsize=4]
[start]         printf{"Start command received"};
[stop]          printf{"Stop command received"};
\end{Verbatim}
Some text to surround the verbatim

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note: the real input file has tabs, but StackExchange seems to convert them to spaces.)

Comment: Drat: was just writing much the same but with `listings` as well :-)

Comment: thnx for the reply. I am curious whether we can make `verbatim` obey tabs or not?

Comment: @SaprativaBhattacharjee Why? The `verbatim` environment is just a simple implementation, while `fancyvrb` has *many* more features.

Comment: so that I don't have to use any extra package

Comment: @SaprativaBhattacharjee I certainly wouldn't undertake the task. What's wrong in loading very stable packages like `fancyvrb`?

Comment: @SaprativaBhattacharjee the verbatim environment defined by the verbatim package can do this, but fancyvrb or listings have a lot more features

Comment: @SaprativaBhattacharjee As the standard `verbatim` environment does not do any parsing of the its content, it would be a major undertaking (relatively) to extend it to deal with the variable length requirement for tabs. The `fancyvrb` package has already done the work: what's the issue?

Comment: @SaprativaBhattacharjee -- the standard `verbatim` environment, as already noted, does not do any parsing.  a trivial change, to only recognize a tab and "space over" a fixed distance, could leave the texts that you intend to be aligned, not aligned, since it would be additive.  not satisfactory at all.